# Implement specific layout

Tags: html, css, canvas, svg, responsive

[Clear template.][1] [Explanation.][2] [Further explanation.][3] [Working demo.][4]

When you are creating a new template, the very first thing is to divide its on sections. As you can see for this demo version we have 3 sections, also middle part has from the top and bottom straight horizontal lines which is continuation of design from the start section. The problem is how to make it responsive.

One of solutions is to export the whole .SVG from design and insert it on the page, but how then align middle content between top and bottom borders, as it would be independent parts.

Currently I did wrapper around whole page, right after body tag and hard coded some of positions, of course it's not the deal.

```
.page__wrap {
        background: url(../img/start/lines.svg);
        background-size: auto 73rem;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 31rem 1rem; 
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 868px) {
        .page__wrap {
            background-size: auto 56rem;
            background-position: 14rem 6rem; 
        } 
    }

    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        .page__wrap {
            background: none; 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: How much do you care about IE/Edge support? Otherwise it would be a case for CSS clip-path.

Comment: I would just make the laptop-on-rhombus section a separate SVG. But change the rhombus so it has a solid colour background (ie blue). Then just make that SVG position absolute or fixed, and have it float on top.  Then to have the cyan and purple lines be on top, just give them a higher z-index. You may have some stacking context issues to deal with, but those should be solveable.

Comment: @ccprog IE/Edge isn't my business rofl, but I didn't get a case of clip-path, how it would help

Comment: @PaulLeBeau That's a clever one! I mean making this laptop with background is pretty much easy to solve problem with this straight lines... Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @PaulLeBeau how to deal with overflow on x axis due to rest invisible part of .SVG element (which is out of viewport)

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I renewed demo, can you please check, is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes. That looks like what I meant. You now just need to tweak the positions and sizes etc.